# how to show the Like button count next to Like Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am building the img tags dynamically and able to share and like them but i want to show the total no of likes next to like button (image). below is my code.

```
function showSharedMediaImages(allSharedMediaList) {
    for ( var i = 0, len = allSharedMediaList.length; i < len; i++) {
        elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = 'getImg/' + allSharedMediaList[i][0] + '/'
                + allSharedMediaList[i][1];
        elem.id = allSharedMediaList[i][2];
        elem.height = '100';
        elem.width = '100';
        elem.alt = 'SPF HYD';
        var image = document.getElementById("sharedMediaLoad");
        image.appendChild(elem);

        //adding like button
        var imgLike = document.createElement("img");
        imgLike.src = "http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumbnail/public/102011/like_icon.png?itok=nkurUMlZ";
        imgLike.id = allSharedMediaList[i][2];
        imgLike.height = '20';
        imgLike.width = '20';
        imgLike.addEventListener("click", likeImage);
        image.appendChild(imgLike);
        // like end here
    }
}
```

then it calls below function to increment the like count in DB and controller returns total like count back to ajax call,

```
function likeImage(e) {
    alert("Like id:" + e.currentTarget.id);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'LikeMediaImage',
        data : "ImageId=" + e.currentTarget.id,
        success : function(likeCount) {
            alert('Media Liked successfully');
            alert('now count of likes is' + likeCount);
            document.getElementsByTagName("likeCount").innerHtml = likeCount + "Likes";
        error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

here i have likeCount as total count of likes.
Please let me know how can i show this count.

Comment: what do you mean by _Please let me know how can i show this count._?  aren't you showing it in this line `document.getElementsByTagName("likeCount").innerHtml = likeCount + "Likes";` ?

Comment: it is not showing the value, can you tell me in-general how we can show the like count for a image.

Comment: I got it guys, thanks. instead of innerHTML i did used textContent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guys, thanks. instead of innerHTML i did used textContent.

Comment: This answer has severe formatting, content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.